# How to select the block of text between two tags (html, xml, ...) in vim?

Tags: select, vim

I want to select the inner text between the xml tag. e.g., I want to select `Default` in this text:

```
<UserID>Default</UserID>
```

I know how to use <kbd>Vi</kbd> to select text in the quote and bracket delimiters (e.g., "", (), [], ...). I tried both <kbd>Vi<</kbd> and <kbd>Vi></kbd>, and neither of them selected any text.

Is there any command to quickly do that?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In normal/command mode, type the commands <kbd>vit</kbd> while in the tag.

mnemonic: "*visual in tag*"

`:help v`
`:help v_it`  (*inner tag block*)
`:help text-objects`

Comment: @imJustice, note that it is very often not needed to select something to be able to act on it: the `c`hange, `d`elete and `y`ank operators all work on text-objects and motions so you can do `yit` if you want to copy the content of that tag, `dit` if you want to delete it or `cit` if you want to change it. **`:help motion.txt` will blow your mind.**

Comment: This is the single most useful tip ever!